# Tensor Network/MPS Code examples for simple condensed matter systems?

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, spin-chains, tensor-network

I've been recently learning about numerical methods in physics, and have come across matrix product states and tensor networks. This is definitely a vague question, but I was wondering if anyone knew of any places where I could find code examples (or pseudocode examples) for simple systems like the Ising Model, (low site) Hubbard model, or XXZ model.

I'm specifically trying to build familiarity with ITensors and Julia, but any resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't e.g. iTensor come with examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ITensor has many tutorials published [here](https://itensor.org/docs.cgi?page=tutorials&vers=cppv3). Please let know if there's something more you'd need which lacks from this page.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice there were C++ examples. I'm unfamiliar with the language, but I think it will help!